# C++ sscanf shows unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, parsing, formatting, stdout, scanf

I have a string that looks like `L"\"4\""` and want to parse it into an integer value.

```
std::wstring wsFoo(L"\"4\"");
int iSize = 1; // Number of characters the number will have
int iResult = -1;
swscanf_s(wsFoo.c_str(), L"\"%*d\"", iSize, &iResult);
wprintf_s(L"%d", iResult);
```

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ the asterisk in `%*d` should mean: **The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.**

Yet the value of `iResult` will be displayed as -1 after this code snippet. Why?

I don't know whether it helps, but I am using MSVC++ 2010.

Comment: Why are you looking at the documentation for `printf()` when you are calling [`swscanf_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3(v=vs.80).aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwwtf9ch%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) explains the use of the * like:

> An asterisk (*) following the percent sign suppresses assignment of
>   the next input field, which is interpreted as a field of the specified
>   type. The field is scanned but not stored.

Note that the format fields for printf and scanf are close but not identical.

Comment: Thanks for the MSDN link - it was very helpful. I was assuming the format fields would be identical.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the meaning of asterisk for printf, not scanf.

If an asterisk (*) is put between the percent and the operator, e. g. %*d, the operator will only match its argument, and not assign any variables.

http://docs.roxen.com/pike/7.0/tutorial/strings/sscanf.xml